# Is it possible to launch a browser directly (like the feature available on notepad++) from Eclipse EE?

Tags: eclipse, browser

In notepad++ there is this awesome feature, where you click on run (on the navigation bar at the top) and select a browser from the list, and notepad++ will automatically show your page on the browser you chose to launch through.

Is there a way to do this from Eclipse (EE for Java)?

Note: On running JSPs, Eclipse opens a web browser in a new tab however that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for!
In Eclipse follow: Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser.
Out there by default 'use internal web browser' is selected, select
'use external web browser' instead. And to get the browser of your choice click
on the 'new' button and add the browser which you want by finding the executable of your
browser (its the exe which you click on to browse the internet like how you're doing right now)

Answer (score 0):

yes there are lot of plugins that can run custom commands in the dos prompt or shell, one of them is StartExplorer and EasyShell plugin. you can then go to preferences and change what command should be run, in this case iexplore.exe will be run.